# SSRS export to excel not setting tabname as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report grouped by department.  I am trying to export to excel and change the spreadsheet tab name to the department name.

I have set the pagename = =Fields!Primary_Department.Value

When I run the report, if the result set for each department is short (up to 40 rows for the department) the export works and the spreadsheet names are changed as expected.
[image: Correct]

When I run the report, if the result set is longer (I use a department with a 60 row result set), the excel spreadsheet tab names get messed up.
[image: Incorrect]

The parameter setup is here
[image: group properties]

I have looked everywhere to try and figure out what I can do to correct this and have not been able to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have set the `PageName` property of the tablix control. It's a little misleading as that will not do what you want.

What you need to do is select the RowGroup that groups by department, then, in the properties panel, expand the `Group` section and set the `PageName` property there.

In the example below by group is called "CategoryDesc" but the process is the same.

[image]

Comment: I added an image with my setup.  It looks similar to what you have.

Comment: that looks OK on the face of it. Can you check the tablix properties and see if the `pagename` has also been set there, if it has, remove that property. When I set the tablix pagename property, I got the same results you originally saw so hopefully it's just that.